# Joomla and WHMCS Auto Login

Tags: php, api, joomla, whmcs

I was integrating auto login system with joomla and WHMCS.

What i want is single login for both joomla and WHMCS.When i logged in joomla, automatically i need my WHMCS system should be logged in and vice verse. I have gone through the WHMCS API, it has AuthAuto login with 'dologin.php' file. But it need redirect to my WHMCS after i login to my joomla, which i don't need.

Even i used 'validatelogin' action in my api call . Also i have hooked 'ClientLogin' and send me a email. When i login through joomla this hook is being called . But my WHMCS when i refresh i am not being logged in.

```
$url = "http://myjoomlasiteurl/includes/api.php"; 
$username = "xxxxxx"; 
$password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$postfields= array();
$postfields["username"] = $username;
$postfields["password"] = md5($password);       
$postfields["accesskey"] = "xxxxx";

$postfields["action"] = "validatelogin";
$postfields["email"] = "user@domain.com";
$postfields["password2"] = "xxxxx"; 


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
if (($result= curl_exec($ch)) !== false) {
 $data= format_result($result);

 $_SESSION['uid'] = $data['userid'];
 $_SESSION['upw'] = $data['passwordhash'];

} 
curl_close($ch);
```

In my WHMCS hook. i have written codes as :

```
function hook_client_logint($vars) {

     ob_start();
     var_dump($_SESSION);
     $content= ob_get_contents();
     @mail('myemailid,'User Login',$content);
     ob_end_clean();
     # Here i ma getting email after i logged in to my Joomla site. 
     session  variable 'uid' and 'upw' are  being set.

 }

 add_hook("ClientLogin",1,"hook_client_login");
```

Comment: I'm stuck on calling a hook when using the API and I found that hooks do not run when you are using the API. I will post back if I find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use redirect for login, just make the visit through `CURL`, get the page check the HTTP Response to be `200`.

You need 2 Joomla plugins (`authenticate,user`)

You need a hook 3 actions:

- addClient
- Create Joomla user
- ClientLogin - make call to login the Joomla user
- ClientLogout - make call to logout the Joomla user
- ClientChangePassword - make call to update the password to Joomla User

to make the Call to Joomla via `CURL` actually can not be done easily because of token.

But you can create a component-view and there you can submit a POST request with the info, in this case email and password

This may help